# No webcam picture with AForge in C#

Tags: c#, image, winforms, aforge

I am just learning C# and I was trying to implement a webcam picture capture program. I'm using the Aforge library, the thing is that my picturebox is not displaying the webcam image and I don't understand why. If anyone knows my error, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DarrenLee.Media;

namespace test4
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        int count = 0;
        Camera myCamera = new Camera();

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GetInfo();
            myCamera.OnFrameArrived += myCamera_OnFrameArrived;
        }
        private void GetInfo()
        {
            var cameraDevices = myCamera.GetCameraSources();
            var cameraResolutions = myCamera.GetSupportedResolutions();

            foreach (var d in cameraDevices)
                cmbCameraDevices.Items.Add(d);

            foreach (var r in cameraResolutions)
                cmbCameraResolutions.Items.Add(r);

            cmbCameraDevices.SelectedIndex = 0;
            cmbCameraDevices.SelectedIndex = 0;

        }
        private void myCamera_OnFrameArrived(object source, FrameArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Image img = e.GetFrame();
            picCamera.Image = img;
        }
        void ComboBox1SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myCamera.ChangeCamera(cmbCameraDevices.SelectedIndex);

        }
        void ComboBox2SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myCamera.Start(cmbCameraDevices.SelectedIndex);
        }
        void Form1FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            myCamera.Stop();
        }
        void BTTsaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filename = Application.StartupPath + @"\" + "Image" + count.ToString();
            myCamera.Capture(filename);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Picture of how it looks when I compile it:
https://i.gyazo.com/6956a07405cd4bf5e74c20bc321bd32e.png

I am connecting the picture box with the content in this line:

**Image img = e.GetFrame();
picCamera.Image = img;**

Comment: when debugging does the variable `img` have a value set?

Comment: @JohnB I am not sure how to use the debugger, but if I did use it correctly it says "the process is running"

Comment: ok...you need to learn this skill - not hard.  also research `how to set a break-point`

Comment: Yes, sorry. I did set a break point and then debug, got the console message, but not sure how to see the exact value of the variable with that.

Comment: then that's what you need to learn next...

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, I'm just going to try something closer to my level, I know I need to learn a lot more. I just got frustrated and that is why I asked but I realized I'm just wasting your time. Sorry and thank you. Have a great night.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you click on the object before writing the code.

Example: Click on the button in the design form then paste the code for **BTTsaveClick** in the newly created method after clicking on the button.

If you are using Visual Studio, you can check if the methods are referenced. If it's not referenced, that means the code won't be read.